# How can an adapter assign background images for buttons in Android?

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter

I am trying to think of a way how my adapter, based on parse data, could assign background images to buttons place in rows within a ListView.
What my app does is downloads json data from a server. Then it is parsed and is used to load an adapter, which shows a list of to-do/done tasks. Next to every task is a button indicating whether it has/hasn’t been done. Any pointers much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176075/custom-listview-with-text-and-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to get and parse json data, create list view with a item layout with required text and image, use the following anomaly to create your custom adapter.

During creating each view in `getView(...)` pass the images you want into the adapter run time. 
Every time you refresh the adapter data, call   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
   public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private ViewHolder Holder;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title, cost;
        Button delete;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int tvResId, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, tvResId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.cost_estimate_list_item, null);

            Holder = new ViewHolder();
            Holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCEListText);
            Holder.cost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCEListPrice);
            Holder.delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bCEListDelBtn);

            v.setTag(Holder);

        } else
            Holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        final Item item = items.get(pos);

        if (item != null) {
            Holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
            Holder.cost.setText("Rs." + item.getPrice());
        }
        Holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                items.remove(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateTotal();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}

class Item {
    private String title, price;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public Item(String t, String p) {
        title = t;
        price = p;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still need help on this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, Ravs. I think I fully get how the above code works and I am trying to implement it. What I am struggling with is how to make it work with a SimpleAdapter, since I am not sure if existing constructors for ArrayAdapter can take all the arguments I am passing. Here is the code representing this part:

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myHabitsList,
      R.layout.my_habits_list_item,
      new String[] {TAG_TITLE, TAG_HABIT_ID}, new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.habit_id});

Comment: You can always use global vars and create the adapter class inside the main class file. This way, you can avoid passing every var via args